# Bash round whole numbers up, down or to nearest hundreds

Tags: bash, numbers, rounding

There is a range of whole positive numbers like

```
827818
6574762
685038
55326902
```

What I need, for example, to round down to hundreds to get accordingly

```
827800
6574700
685000
55326900
```

Many ideas how to round up, down or nearest hundreds using Javascript, for example

```
Math.floor(number / 100) * 100;
```

but is it possible to do the same in Bash ?

Comment: The expected output contains a small error. According to your description `6574762` should be rounded to `6574800`, not `6574700`.

Comment: `sed 's/..$/00/' file`?

Comment: you may want to clarify what you want to do ... truncate all numbers (ie, replace last 2 digits with `00`) ... or round up/down based on the last 2 digits (ie, >=50 == round up / <=49 == round down); with `00`

Comment: You said in bash; see this question, in particular the excellent Gnu coreutil called [`numfmt`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44087/11836) that does formatting,rounding, units, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what is meant by "in Bash", but perhaps one of :

```
$ cat input
827818
6574762
685038
55326902
$ awk '{printf "%d00\n", $0 / 100}' input
827800
6574700
685000
55326900
```

or (if all the values are greater than 100!):

```
while read x; do echo "${x%[0-9][0-9]}00"; done < input
```

If you want to handle the case where values are less than 100 and deal with negative values, you could do:

```
while read x; do if test "${x#-}" -gt 100; then echo "${x%[0-9][0-9]}00"; else echo 0; fi; done < input
```

but it's almost certainly better to stick with `awk`.

Comment: what syntax if single number as variable, for example command line `number=6575675; awk '{printf "%d00\n", $0 / 100}' $number` - does not work, but I feel my syntax is wrong

Comment: Either `echo "$number" | awk '{printf "%d00\n", $0 / 100}'` or `awk -v n="$number" 'BEGIN{ printf "%d00\n", n / 100; exit}'`

Comment: THX ! Your answer is the best for me

Answer (score 1):

To round to the *nearest* 100, use `(number + 50) / 100 * 100`.
You can modify each line to this calculation, then run those expressions through `bc` to evaluate them.

```
sed 's|.*|(&+50)/100*100|' file | bc
```

Comment: pls, to get clear - what if command line for single number sed `'s|.*|(&+50)/100*100|' 88788785 | bc` - what correct syntax should be ?

Comment: If you don't have a file, you can use a here-string:  `'s|.*|(&+50)/100*100|' <<< 88788785 | bc`. But for one input number there is no real need for `sed`. You could directly write `bc <<< '(88788785+50)/100*100'` or even `echo $(((88788785+50)/100*100))`.

Answer (score 0):

For rounding down you can also rev the full number and use cut -c 1-2 on the output, which you can then rev again to obtain the full number's last two digits. Then you can do calc or bc (full number - first output) to round down to nearest 100.

Or you can remove the last two digits of the full number with bc using scale=0 (or no scale) and divide by 100, after which you can just multiply by 100 again;

```
DIV_100=$( echo "123456789/100" | bc ) && echo "$DIV_100*100" | bc

and in loop

while read -r line; do
echo "$line" > full_number_1.txt
FULL_NUMBER=$(<full_number_1.txt)
DIV_100=$( echo "$FULL_NUMBER / 100" | bc )
echo "$DIV_100 * 100" | bc >> output_file
done < input.txt
```

Or use echo ${...%??}

```
echo "${number%??}*100" | bc

..loop..

while read -r line; do
echo "${line%??}*100" | bc >> output
done < input.txt
```

Many options here for rounding down.

Rounding up will require some alterations but is equally possible in many ways. For example:

```
DIV_100=$( echo "123456789/100" | bc ) && echo "($DIV_100*100)+100" | bc

and in loop

while read -r line; do
echo "$line" > full_number_1.txt
FULL_NUMBER=$(<full_number_1.txt)
DIV_100=$( echo "$FULL_NUMBER / 100" | bc )
echo "($DIV_100 * 100)+100" | bc >> output_file
done < input.txt
```

or with echo ${...%??}

```
echo "(${number%??}*100)+100" | bc

..loop..

while read -r line; do
echo "(${line%??}*100)+100" | bc >> output
done < input.txt
```